# Set items column by column in TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I have a little question ;

I currently have  2 lists from differents objects that i can't change ;

```
private ObservableList<People1> people1List = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private ObservableList<People2> people2List = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

When i try to add my data in the table, i only have the second values in each column :

```
people2List  = FXCollections.observableArrayList(people1.getObservable().values());
peopleTable.setItems(people2List.sorted(new DataValueComparator()));

people1List = FXCollections.observableArrayList(peopl2.getObservable().values());
peopleTable.setItems(people1List.sorted(new DataValueComparator()));
```

How i could do "setItems()" on a column ? and then have 2 differents observables objets in columns ?

I know if i do setItems twice, it will overwrite the first one, but there is method setItems on a column

Please, any help would be appreciated

Comment: So you want to add the two ObservableList to the same TableView?

Comment: Yes, that's it, because i've 2 ObservableList from differents objects that i would like to put 1 column each

Comment: There is no way to do something like 
@FXML
private TableView<people1,people2> peopleTable;

or myColumnPeople1.setItems(mylist) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to display two observable list into the same tableview it's the following:

1. Create an abstract type, it can be abstract class or interface (ex: Person) which should be inherited by the Person1 and Person2 class.
2. Create only one ObservableList of Persons which contains the people1List and people2List.
3. When you want to set the values in the TableView you should use `instaceof` for checking if a Person is `instaceof Person1` or `instanceof Person2` and now you can set the person in the first or the second column.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set different items for each column.

You could however use the `cellValueFactory`s to extract the values from the lists:

```
final ObservableList<People1> source1 = people1List.sorted(new DataValueComparator());
final ObservableList<People2> source2 = people2List.sorted(new DataValueComparator());

TableView<Integer> tableView = new TableView<>();

InvalidationListener listener = o -> {
    // keep items size the max of list sizes
    int newSize = Math.max(source1.size(), source2.size());
    if (tableView.getItems().size() > newSize) {
        tableView.getItems().subList(newSize, tableView.getItems().size()).clear();
    } else {
        for (int i = tableView.getItems().size(); i < newSize; i++) {
            tableView.getItems().add(i);
        }
    }
};

source1.addListener(listener);
source2.addListener(listener);

TableColumn<Integer, People1> column1 = ...
column1.setCellValueFactory(cd -> Bindings.valueAt(source1, cd.getValue()));

TableColumn<Integer, People2> column2 = ...
column2.setCellValueFactory(cd -> Bindings.valueAt(source2, cd.getValue()));

tableView.getColumns().addAll(column1, column2);
```

Comment: Why the TableView is an Integer Tableview ?

Comment: @sleakerz Because the value for each row is an index into the lists .

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't show two different Lists in ListView.
You can solve your problem with an Interface like Dina described.

Or when you realy can't change the two People classes. You can make a class with two Constructors for each People Class and represent a List of these object in your ListView like:

```
public class People{
        //some variable
        public People(People1 p1){
        }

        public People(People2 p2){
        }
    }

    private ObservableList<People> peopleList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

And display the `peopleList` in your ListView.